# Display mobile view of website to user by giving URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, remote-server

I want to show user how their website look in mobile so for this purpose I used iframe in my website to load their website by giving url but for some security reasons site not loaded there are cors policy issues. I also use curl but some files not loading due to security. Is there any API or proper way to load like in real mobile device.

```php
<form method="get">
  <input name="website_url" type="url">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe src="<?=$_GET['website_url']?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: You could always use something in Chrome - https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop

Comment: You could open a new browser window, of the correct width, using Javascript. See: [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) This will probably work, but is, of course, not the same as an in page iframe.

Comment: In order to help you understanding what is preventing your browser to load the iframe content we should see the actual content of your browser console. I expect there are some errors displayed there explaining why the browser is unable to load the iframe content. It is probably related with security headers which are included in the page you want to show inside the iframe. This can happen, for instance, due to the value of the Content-Security-Policy response header or the X-Frame-Options header.